# Confixx Admin Backend: Error 500 - Premature end of script headers: index.php

Tags: permissions

I think I messed up my permissions on my server witch is running confixx.
Mistakenly I changed owner and Group -R for /home. So everything was messed up.

I already fixed the most of it but the directory "/home/www/confixx/" is not working.
Still getting:

**Error 500 -
Premature end of script headers: index.php**

Folder permission is:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root     4096 Apr 29 20:42 confixx
```

I've already done:

```
chmod -R 755 confixx/  
chmod -R 644 confixx/*.php
```

But still getting the error.

Is there any option in confixx to restore the default permissions?
Or someone know how to fix this problem?
Is the user for the confixx folder correct?
I couldn't find any docs about the default.